# How to resolve the FileNotFoundException error in my DAL when connecting to a database?

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, data-access-layer

I'm using data access layer where I'm defining my entities & ApplictionDbContext. I do have separate web project and trying to connect to database but getting following error in DAL layer.

[image]

Comment: Likely to be an issue with the dependencies, please post what you have set.

Comment: there is an extra branch for Entity Framework Core. Its more lightweight then Entity Framework 7. Could cause problems that you are using the wrong versions. It depends on the SQL Server in the background and your system setup

Answer (score 0):

I tried this myself and able to resolve the issue, you need to remove "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" from the references

Answer (score -1):

Try to add this to your "project.json" file under "dependencies" part:

```
"System.Interactive.Async": "3.0.0"
```

Comment: Resolved - Thanks for your help, you have to remove "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" from project references